# IndexError when trying to append name to end of file name before suffix

Tags: python

Using Python 3.8.3, I am trying to add a string to the end of my file names so they will be uniquely identified when combined into a large directory. In this case, I am trying to add a simple `_a` to the end of the file name, but before the suffix.

For example, all of my files (workplace directory contains JPG and TXT files) need to go from a file name of `P025525_002.jpg` to `P025525_002_a.jpg` and the same for TXT files.

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "add_name.py", line 12, in <module>
    new_name = '{1} {2} {3}'.format(f_name + str('_a'), f_ext)
IndexError: Replacement index 2 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Here's the script I have written:

```
import os

os.chdir('E:\\Users\\rest_of\\file_path')

def increment():
    global COUNT
    COUNT = COUNT + 1

for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    new_name = '{1} {2} {3}'.format(f_name + str('_a'), f_ext)
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Comment: You are passing 2 arguments to `.format`, but using `{3}` requires that you pass at least 4. Even if you use `{0} {1} {2}` you need to pass at least 3 arguments to `.format`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `new_name` to :

```
new_name = f'{f_name}_a{f_ext}'
```

You problem with your `.format()` is you specified three place holders, but you passed 2 values. Also note that you should count from `0` not `1`, `3` is out of range:

```
new_name = '{0}_a{1}'.format(f_name, f_ext).
```

btw in your case you could skip numbers and use bare `{}`.

I recommend f-string though.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line -

```
for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    new_name = '{1} {2} {3}'.format(f_name + str('_a'), f_ext)
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

to -

```
for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    new_name = '{0} {1}'.format(f_name + str('_a'), f_ext)
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

Or use **f-strings** which is more readable -

```
new_name = f'{f_name}_a{f_ext}'
```

This worked for me!

Comment: `str('_a') == '_a'`

Answer (score 1):

```
for f in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
    new_name = '{2} {3}'.format(f_name + str('_a'), f_ext)
    os.rename(f, new_name)
```

`+` between 2 strings is used for string concatenation. So the strings are actually combined to one single string. So in theory, there are 2 arguments but you have given to pass 3 arguments. That is the problem